# How to set compiler environment inside Rails app

Tags: ruby, compilation, compiler-construction, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to compile user's code (any language) taken through form using Rails app. I have tried using online compiler APIs like 'Judge0' but I need to set up an environment inside my app so that the compilation and execution can be done on the server itself.

Comment: This is really way too broad. Compile what? Any language is *a lot of languages*. Are you supporting Fortran? Cobol? APL? This is a huge project. Look at [Codepad](http://codepad.org) as an example.

Comment: Depending on the language you could `eval` the string which should turn that string into executable code for that particular source code

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval

Also I wanted to add that assuming your Rails server has these other languages setup for example lets you have python interpreter installed and users can input python and execute it, you could "shell out" using `Open3` lib: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Open3.html